# Variance of a function g(x)=(2x+1)^2 where x is random variable of values 3 6 9 with probabilities 1/6 1/2 and 1/3 respectively

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Solving for $Var[g(x)]$ by computing $E[g(x)^2]-(E[g(x)])^2$ gives the answer:

[[image: Values of g(x) and g(x)^2]][image: Answer by directly substituting in formula]

While solving for variance by breaking down the g(x) into individual values gives
$Var[g(x)] = Var[(2x+1)^2]$

$Var[(4x^2)+(4x)+1] = Var[4x^2]+Var[4x]+0 = 
16(E[x^4]-(E[x^2])^2 + E[x^2] - E[x])^2)$

$E[x^4] = 2745/4 ,  E[x^2] = 46.5 , E[x] = 6.5$

$Var[g(x)] = 11048$

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Variance by using E[(g(x))^2]-(E[(g(x)])^2 gives 12752 answer while by simplifying it gives the 11048 value

Comment: Variance is not linear for correlated random variables, and $x$ and $x^2$ are correlated. $$\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(x^2, x)&=\mathsf E(x^3)-\mathsf E(x^2)\,\mathsf E(x)\\[1ex]&=213/4\end{align}$$ You would need to use the Bilinearity of Covariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
Var(4X^2+4X+1) &= 16Var(X^2+X)\\
&= 16 Cov(X^2+X, X^2+X) \\
&= 16[Var(X^2)+Var(X) + 2Cov(X^2, X)]
\end{align}

\begin{align}Cov(X^2, X) &= E[X^3] - E[X^2]E[X] \\
&=\left(3^3 \cdot \frac16 + 6^3\cdot\frac12 + 9^3\cdot \frac13\right)-(46.5)(6.5) \\
&=53.25\end{align}

$$11048+32(53.25)=12752$$